# how I could pass variable inside awk match?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an awk command.
I need to use `i` variable but my command does not work when I do.

```
"fechaName": "1","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "2","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "5","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"fechaName": "4","firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"fechaName": "7","xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

When I use 5 instead of **"i"** it works

```
awk  -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ for( i=2; i<=7; i++ ) if( match($2, /5"/) )  print $0 }'   sumacomando
```

this is my command

```
awk  -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ for( i=2; i<=7; i++ ) if( match($2, /**i**"/) )  print $0 }'   sumacomando

awk  -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ for( i=2; i<=7; i++ ) if( match($2, /i"/) )  print $0 }'   sumacomando
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: only need sort  by fechaName 2 to 7 with my command not external  methods like sort or asort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not sort all the records just with one pass.

To answer your main question literally to match a field with a variable you just need to do `match($2,i)` without `/.../` (or `match($2, i "\"")` for `i` followed by a `"`. Using normal string concatenation syntax).

Even this one will bring you correct results for a record containing "4":

```
awk '{i=4}$0 ~ "\"" i "\""' file1 #(string concatenation yelds to "4")
```

But this one , though it will work without error, will not automatically sort the data with one pass as you might expect:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<8;i++) if ($0 ~ "\"" i "\"") print}' file1
```

To sort all the records you need first to load all records in memory and then print them in a sorting order.

This is a different approach that works with your sample file:

```
awk  -F"[\"]" '{a[$4]?a[$4]=a[$4] ORS $0:a[$4]=$0;last=NR}END{for (i=1;i<=last;i++) if (a[i]) print a[i]}' file1
```

[See online test here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVHBYRWsxY0JvYk0)

Using delimiter  `"`  text of first line `"fechaName": "1",....` will split in 4 pieces and `1` (field $4) can be used directly as an integer.

The part `a[$4]?a[$4]=a[$4] ORS $0:a[$4]=$0` is just an if-then-else:

if `a[$4]` (==> `a[1]` for first line) has already a value then add this line to the previous a[$4] contents using the Output Record Separator (ORS) which is a new line (or could be a litteral "\n") - else just apply $0 to a[$4]

Finally in end section we just print this array a.

**We need to say here that sort will be hell faster than awk for this operation:**

```
LC_ALL=C sort -t"\"" -k3 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to print the lines containing 1 to 7. That would be something like

```
awk '/"fechaName": "[1-7]"/ { print }'
```

Comment: thanks ; I understand but I need to modify this posted script for sorting purpose

Comment: this command not sort print in same order

Comment: @AlejandroDiego Then please write a suitable problem description.

Comment: I know but I put in my description that I need pass variable inside match

Comment: if( match($2, /i"/)